# Show only last 10 lines from text file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file, text

I am not programmer so I dont know how to edit it.

I am using code which I found here in stackoverflow and want to show only 10 last lines from text file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadXMLDoc()
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","status.txt",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadXMLDoc();
</script>
<div id="myDiv">Current Status</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("loadXMLDoc()", 2000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
... = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n").slice(-10).join("\n");
```